# Python Social Auth multiple scopes extra data

Tags: python, django, google-oauth

I'm using Python Social Auth for our app and I recently created a two-scope Google signin. The idea was to allow users to sign in with google but then to escalate the scope to allow us to read their emails and parse through them for relevant content. I followed the advice outlined in the docs: http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/use_cases.html#multiple-scopes-per-provider and created a new backend:

```
from social.backends.google import GoogleOAuth2
class GoogleEmailOAuth2(GoogleOAuth2):
    name = 'google-email'
```

and then added the necessary pieces to our settings.py (and all the necessary urls):

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_EMAIL_SCOPE = ['email', 'profile', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read']
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_EMAIL_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {'access_type': 'offline'}
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_EMAIL_EXTRA_DATA = [
    ('id', 'user_id'),
    ('email', 'user_email'),
    ('refresh_token', 'refresh_token', True),
    ('expires_in', 'expires'),
    ('token_type', 'token_type', True)
]
```

and everything seems to work except that the UserSocialAuth object created does not contain any thing in extra_data...I've used the same scope for the normal SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_EXTRA_DATA and it works perfectly, but still nada for the custom backend. Thanks very much in advance for any suggestions.

Edit: tried a few different approaches but still can't set the data.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have the same issue so can't answer the question, but one suggestion is to put a debugging breakpoint in the `load_extra_data` pipeline function and follow it from there:

```
def load_extra_data(backend, details, response, uid, user, *args, **kwargs):
    #
    # <-- Add your debugger of choice, e.g. 
    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    #
    social = kwargs.get('social') or \
             backend.strategy.storage.user.get_social_auth(backend.name, uid)
    if social:
        extra_data = backend.extra_data(user, uid, response, details,
                                        *args, **kwargs)
        social.set_extra_data(extra_data)
```

https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/v0.2.13/social/pipeline/social_auth.py#L82-L88